# How to describe the interaction between a neutrino and a nucleus?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, standard-model, neutrinos

I know the basics of particle physics and QFT.

How do you write it down the interaction between a a neutrino and an atomic nucleus (or many of them)? what equation or Lagrangian or anything else do you write down to model?

And, once you have that equation/anything else, how do you proceed to calculate relevant experimental consequences?

Comment: Are you interested in low energy $\nu+n \to p +e$ reactions or deep inelastic scattering?

Comment: This question is likely to be closed at present for lack of detail. For example, what kind of experiment are you interested in modeling? What is the center-of-mass energy of the neutrino-nucleus system you're interested in? This determines what is "relevant" to that particular experiment, and also determines the kinds of interactions that dominate under those conditions.

Comment: Please review your [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-cross-section-formulae.pdf), equations (49.18,19) and sharpen your questions accordingly.

Comment: @CosmasZachos you have helped me a lot by giving me this huge source of information I didn't know about. I'll get better.

Comment: @user35319 let's say low energy, where do I start?

Comment: Low energy in [Baker et al.](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.23.2499?casa_token=rnNwtqgGNQYAAAAA%3AcBhOYaMqHdYXgJUfhNArV8j10B9UrhLAezeSQGDnkkD533rgoCDrudPH_GwbM6aE2IIyu8zJKwXALA).